Electro muscular stimulation suit, exercises - do you need them?
Background
Electro muscular stimulation (EMS) suit systems like Katalyst, include apps.  I've got one of these Katalyst suits and have had good results with it.
The suit's videos run on an iPad or iPhone that direct one through a series of exercises over 20 minute sessions. In the default setting, the intensity of the stimulation increases over the 20 minutes.  One can adjust the starting point and the default increase adjusts proportionately with that setting (I think).  One can get very significant training effect in a 20 minute session at the right intensity levels.
With respect to my strength/conditioning sessions (2 per week), I can increase intensity by adjusting the starting point each session.  I estimate that if I never missed a session and increased the starting point each successive session, I wouldn't reach the suit's maximum for 24 months.  Then one could step intensity down a bit and add another session each week and start the regular increasing again.
So the suit has lots of room with which to work.
I don't rely on the suit for all my training.  I do 10k-20k walks 5 times per week.  Cross country machine (easy on my old knees) once a week (sometimes augmented by wearing the Katalyst suit). I also do timed static contractions (SuperSlow) to put load on my skeleton once or twice a week.  All pretty time efficient.
Heart of the matter
Most of the exercise movements in the videos replicate the movements of body weight exercise or lifting free weights and some of the reps of the exercises end in isometric holds or tension, but overall the suit relies principally of the EMS for effect.
Question
I can't get an objective answer to this kind of question from Katalyst (to which I have no affiliation) and they don't have a discussion forum, which led me here.
From a technical perspective, given the intensity of the EMS and the ability to continually raise the level over time, does one really need to do these exercise movements?
Not that I'd stop doing them completely, I can make a case that if one experiences the stimulation across the range of muscle contraction and extension it might prove more effective.
I just wonder how much it really adds to the ultimate training effect?
Thoughts appreciated.

This might be the most interesting question I’ve seen on this site so far.

You still need to contract the muscles to get the benefits of the EMS, no? Otherwise the stimulus might be too low for increasing adaptation in the muscles beyond a certain point. I'm affraid Katalyst doesn't know (or the answer is not good for their marketing).

@Luciano - The electrical stimulation itself causes the muscles to contract and relax repeatedly, mimicking the effects of exercise.

I can contract and relax my biceps without bending my elbows, I guess that's trhe extent of what the EMS will do if you don't move with it. That should give an idea of effectiveness. But I'm curious about it as well.

@Luciano - Not at all.  The contractions caused by EMS (at least with the Katalyst suit) get very very very intense.  When I push the intensity a bit more then I intended I can have serious muscle soreness for 3 days.

I found one study on The efficacy and safety of whole-body electromyostimulation (WB-EMS) and another one on the effects of different EMS Methods in athletes . In the first study they use a very similar suit with electrodes distributed around the body, the second study reviewed various EMS devices typically used for strength training in athletes.
EMS and traditional resistance training both improve strength, but their mechanisms differ. EMS directly stimulates muscles via electrical impulses, bypassing the nervous system, which can be beneficial for activating hard-to-recruit muscle fibers. Traditional resistance training involves voluntary muscle contractions, which integrate neurological and muscular adaptations.
Research suggests EMS is most effective as a complement to traditional training, particularly for highly trained athletes or targeted rehabilitation. On its own, EMS is less effective in achieving holistic strength and functional fitness improvements.
While EMS alone can stimulate muscle hypertrophy and strength, it does not produce the same functional improvements or neuromuscular adaptations as exercises involving voluntary effort.
